# Getting .servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets

I am trying to learn from [this tutorial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/mvc/spring-4-rest-hello-world-example/) how to write a REST API. It is supposed to replace `${msg}` inside the `index.jsp` file with a message.

The Problem is when I try to call the servlet at `http://localhost:8080/MahlzeitServer/helloWorld/hello` I am getting this response from tomcat:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /MahlzeitServer/WEB-INF/helloWorld.jsp

type:        Status report
message:     /MahlzeitServer/WEB-INF/helloWorld.jsp
description: The requested resource is not available.
```

I'm note sure why this is the case. If I go to `localhost:8080/MahlzeitServer` the site gets displayed but `${msg}` is not replaced. Here is the **index.jsp** file:

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World2!</h2>
<h3>Your Message : ${msg}</h3>  
</body>
</html>
```

**HelloWorldController.java**

```
package com.mahlzeit.server;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/helloWorld")
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("msg", "JCG Hello World!");
        return "helloWorld";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/displayMessage/{msg}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayMessage(@PathVariable String msg, ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("msg", msg);
        return "helloWorld";
    }
}
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- CHANGED <context:component-scan base-package="com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise" />-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mahlzeit.server" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: helloWorld != helloworld. The case matters.

Comment: @JBNizet Thx for the hint. Unfortunately this wasn't the problem :/

Comment: It is *one* of the problems. What is the package of the class HelloWorldController?

Comment: @JBNizet `package com.mahlzeit.server;`

Comment: Then it won't be scanned, since you said in your config file that the base package was com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise

Comment: @JBNizet Okay that makes sense.. changed that but it still does not work..

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us what your new code is, what your new URL is, and what your new error message is.

Comment: @JBNizet I added that. Now I get no error at all (at least not in the console). Getting HTTP 404 (Resource not available). Do the files in target have to land in tomcats directory?

Comment: Use your debugger to know if the controller is executed. Or add print statements to know. My guess now is that there is no view /WEB-INF/helloWorld.jsp

Comment: @JBNizet Okay, the breakpoint gets hit! At least something .. but it gets not displayed correctly in the browser.

Comment: @JBNizet Alright I got it. The file was missing. I mixed two tutorials up.. though that upper/lower case thing was more or less from the one I referred to. Now it gets displayed. For some reason `${msg}` does not get replaced with the correct value but I guess that's another problem. Do you want to provide an answer here? :)

Comment: Feel free to accept Aniket's answer. I have plenty of points already.

Comment: @JBNizet Alright. :) Thank you for your help! If you got a hint why ${msg} gets not replaced that would be great - if not not problem I guess I'd get behind that. :D

Comment: No clear idea. I find it strange that your web.xml uses version 2.3, and not a recent version of the spec (3.0 for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like case issue. Try

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/helloworld")
public class HelloWorldController {
...
```

instead of

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/helloWorld")
public class HelloWorldController {
```

or try hitting

```
http://localhost:8080/MahlzeitServer/helloWorld/hello
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:8080/MahlzeitServer/helloworld/hello
```